# Kernel 3.14.1 compilation errors

Tags: kernel

I installed kernel 3.14.1 and there seem to be no issues.

```
uname -r
3.14.1-031401-generic
```

However, when I try to go to the folder and try to do a make it fails. I see that multiple files are missing. Any idea how I get them?

```
 sudo make
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.14.1-031401-generic/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you run `make menuconfig`? Why do you want to compile the kernel? If you want to build Ubuntu linux-image packages you will need to build with dpkg tools eg. `dpkg-buildpackage`

Comment: The error says that you are missing a `.config` file in the kernel srouce directory. Try copying the config from your existing installation from `/boot/config-$(uname -r)` into the source directory and run `make` again. my two cents!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile a kernel, move to the kernel directory (suppose linux 3.14):

```
cd linux 3.14
```

then `make defconfig`,  which automatically creates the x86 config for the kernel.

If you wish add extra features (custom kernel building), use `make menuconfig`.